# unable to connect to openfire server with external ip

Tags: server, dns, client, openfire

I'm trying to connect to openfire server using spark. I have dynamic dns, made port forwarding on port 5222 in d-link router. When i'm logging with host name as private ip for example "192.168.0.101" - connection is established, but when i'm setting my domain (pizokas.hopto.org) as host name i get the following error

> Unknown connection error. Please review logs for the following information.

But there are no logs in openfire server, so i assume packets are dropped in router. I have firewall turned off. At this point i can't find information why the connection cannot be established. I'm using my own laptop as server and as a client, os win 10. Maybe somebody had similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

The connection was established when i was trying to connect to server from outside of lan